# Pandas Dataframe Stacking versus Pivoting

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using pandas to reshape some string/numeric-valued responses, and I've run into some behavior that's a bit counterintuitive.

Can someone explain the difference between the dataframes `stacked` and `pivoted` below, and why `pivoted2` raises the `DataError` even though no `aggfunc` is passed?

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'ID': pd.Series(['x']*3 + ['y']*3,index = range(6)),
     'Count': pd.Series([1,2,1,1,1,1], index = range(6)),
     'Value_type': pd.Series(['foo','foo','bar','foo','bar','baz'], index = range(6)),
     'Value': pd.Series(range(1,7),index = range(6))}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

d2 = {'ID': pd.Series(['x']*3 + ['y']*3,index = range(6)),
     'Count': pd.Series([1,2,1,1,1,1], index = range(6)),
     'Value_type': pd.Series(['foo','foo','bar','foo','bar','baz'], index = range(6)),
     'Value': pd.Series(list('abcdef'),index = range(6))}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)

restacked = df.set_index(['ID','Count','Value_type']).unstack()
print restacked

restacked2 =  df2.set_index(['ID','Count','Value_type']).unstack()
print restacked2

pivoted = pd.pivot_table(df,rows = ['ID','Count'],cols = 'Value_type',values = 'Value')
print pivoted

## raises DataError('No numeric types to aggregate'), 
## even though no aggregation function is passed.
pivoted2 = pd.pivot_table(df2,rows = ['ID','Count'],cols = 'Value_type',values = 'Value')
print pivoted2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [default agg function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.tools.pivot.pivot_table.html) is [`np.mean`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) (even though you didn't pass it explicitly this is what is being used), which doesn't make sense on strings, in fact it raises an AttributeError when passed an object array - so pandas complains when you try to do this.

You could pass [`np.sum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html):

```
In [11]: pd.pivot_table(df2, rows=['ID', 'Count'], cols='Value_type',
                        values='Value', aggfunc=np.sum)
Out[11]: 
Value_type  bar  baz foo
ID Count                
x  1          c  NaN   a
   2        NaN  NaN   b
y  1          e    f   d
```

Or take the first item using [`iloc[0]`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing-loc-iloc-and-ix):

```
In [12]: pd.pivot_table(df2, rows=['ID', 'Count'], cols='Value_type',
                        values='Value', aggfunc=lambda x: x.iloc[0])
Out[12]: 
Value_type  bar  baz foo
ID Count                
x  1          c  NaN   a
   2        NaN  NaN   b
y  1          e    f   d
```

Note: that this is the same as `pivoted2['Value']`, you can make this output the same as `pivoted2` if you pass a *list* to values to aggregate:

```
In [13]: pd.pivot_table(df2, rows=['ID', 'Count'], cols=['Value_type'], 
                        values=['Value'], aggfunc=lambda x: x.iloc[0])
Out[13]: 
           Value         
Value_type   bar  baz foo
ID Count                 
x  1           c  NaN   a
   2         NaN  NaN   b
y  1           e    f   d
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. Can you explain the difference between the stacked dataframe and the pivoted one?

Comment: @MichaelK it's just that pivot_table doesn't label (as the first row of the multiindex) the values you are grabbing, *unless* you pass a list of value columns. Which is to say: restacked['Value'] == pivoted.